# VBA Macro Run-time error 9: subscript out of range - if statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project where i need to use a GA. I have encountered the following Error in my code.

The following code is to do the crossover of the GA. Most of the variables are entered through an userform. *Note this code may contain more errors.

My variables:

```
Dim FitValarr() As Long
Dim fitsmall As Long
Dim Poparr() As Integer
Dim PopSize As Long
Dim Cross_Prob As Double
Dim overallRandom As Single
Dim FitValarr() As Long
Dim fitsmall As Long
Dim newChildarr() As Integer
Dim newChildfit As Integer
Dim child1() As Integer
Dim child2() As Integer
Dim fitvalchild1 As Integer
Dim fitvalchild2 As Integer
Dim crossoverpos As Integer
Dim chromosomerandom As Integer
Dim fitbig As Integer
Dim i As Long, j As Long, counter As Long
Dim Chromolength As Integer
```

the code:

```
Chromolength = varchromolength * aVariables  'usual value is around 30 = (10*3)
ReDim Poparr(1 To PopSize, 1 To Chromolength)
ReDim FitValarr(1 To PopSize)                 'popsize is around 10 -50
ReDim newChildarr(1 To Chromolength) As Integer
ReDim child1(1 To Chromolength) As Integer
ReDim child2(1 To Chromolength) As Integer

 'chosing two random chromosomes
Dim rand1 As Integer
Dim rand2 As Integer

rand1 = Int(Rnd * PopSize)               'generate random value between 1-50
rand2 = Int(Rnd * PopSize)               'same as above

Do While rand1 = rand2
       rand2 = Int(Rnd * PopSize)        'checking that the two random values isn't the same
Loop


If overallRandom < Cross_Prob Then                  

    If FitValarr(rand1) > FitValarr(rand2) Then    
        Do While rand1 = rand2
        rand2 = Int(Rnd * PopSize)
        Loop
    Else
        Do While rand1 = rand2                     
        rand1 = Int(Rnd * PopSize)
        Loop
    End If

    crossoverpos = Int(Rnd * Chromolength)
    Do While crossoverpos < 1 & crossoverpos > Chromolength
    Loop

    'do crossover and assign it to child# array
    For i = 1 To crossoverpos                                   
        child1(i) = Poparr(rand1, i)                            
        child2(i) = Poparr(rand2, i)                            
    Next i

    For i = crossoverpos To Chromolength
        child1(i) = Poparr(rand2, i)                            
        child2(i) = Poparr(rand1, i)                            
    Next i

    'fitness of the two offsprings
    For i = 1 To Chromolength                                  
        counter = Chromolength

        Do While counter > 0
            fitvalchild1 = fitvalchild1 + child1(counter) * 2 ^ (i - 1)
            fitvalchild2 = fitvalchild2 + child2(counter) * 2 ^ (i - 1)
            counter = counter - 1
        Loop
    Next i

    If fitvalchild1 > fitvalchild2 Then                        
        newChildfit = fitvalchild1                             
        For i = 1 To Chromolength
        newChildarr(i) = child1(i)                             
        Next i

    Else                                                       
        newChildfit = fitvalchild2                             
        For i = 1 To Chromolength
        newChildarr(i) = child2(i)                             
        Next i

    End If

Else                                                            
    newChildfit = FitValarr(rand1)                              
    For i = 1 To Chromolength
        newChildarr(i) = Poparr(rand1, i)                       
    Next i

End If 'end crossover
```

the error is in the crossover code:

```
 If FitValarr(rand1) > FitValarr(rand2) Then
```

I apologise for the long code. I am fairly new to VBA and still struggeling bit.

Comment: Have you tried debugginh the code, to see where the error occurs?

Comment: Your comments say that chromoLength is around 30, but all of your fixed arrays, including newChildArr() are set to (20).  And in the last ELSE clause, you assign chromoLength elements to newChildArr().  Seems like that would cause this error.

Comment: ok i edited it a bit still same error in if statement

Comment: Your `rand2 = Int(Rnd * PopSize)` will occasionally result in a `rand2` value of zero, and your arrays are 1-based, so that's likely your problem.

Comment: Straight from the help for `Rnd` - To produce random integers in a given range, use this formula:
`Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)`

Comment: Using line numbers in source code may poit to the. exact error location. See.  http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/Visual_Basic/Tip_2_Use_line_numbers_in_your_source_code.htm